# Prove that the concept of a vertex does not depend upon the parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry

Any hints on how to start the proof?

The curvature of a regular curve $\beta(t)$ (not necessarily unit speed) can be written as:

$\kappa$ = $\frac{|\beta'(t) \times \beta''(t)|}{|\beta'(t)|}$. Then $\kappa$ has a relative max or min when values of t give $\kappa'(t)$ = 0.

Comment: Don't worry about the formula for $\kappa$. Just think about the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin If I say s(t) is another parametrization, then [k(s(t))]' = k'(s(t))s'(t), and the vertex is when k(s(t)) is a relative max or min, so when k'(s(t))s'(t) = 0. I've been thinking about this and I just can't see what the next step would be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would rather write $(\kappa\circ s)'(t)$ for your first quantity. The point is that $s'(t)\ne 0$ (why?), and so $\kappa'(s(t_0))=0$ if and only if $(\kappa\circ s)'(t_0) = 0$, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin s'(t) can't equal zero, because it's a parameter for a regular curve?

Comment: Well, $s'(t)$ is the speed of the parametrized curve, and regularity tells you that ...

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your help! I posted an answer to my question below.